# What HTML and/or Markdown code is allowed in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown, formatting

What HTML and/or Markdown code is allowed in comments?

Answer (score 4):

Comments can be formatted with a subset of Markdown: **bold** (`**bold**`), *italic* (`*italic*`), ***bold italic***, and `monospace/code` (`` `code` ``) are allowed. URLs will be automatically converted into actual links. Links are also allowed by using the syntax: `[link text](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com)`.

Comment: Comments can be formatted with a subset of Markdown: **bold** (`**bold**`), *italic* (`*italic*`), ***bold italic***, and `monospace/code` (`\`code\``) are allowed. URLs will be automatically converted into actual links. Links are also allowed by using the syntax: `[link text](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com)`.

Comment: don't forget `[link text](http://link.url "alt text")` [see](http://no.where "yay for alt texts!")

Comment: ***Bold italic*** text is shown in *your* comment, so it apparently works in comments after all. Does this reflect a change in the StackExchange software, which your answer should be edited to reflect?

Comment: @EliahKagan: It appears so. Updated.

Comment: How did you edit your first comment, which is far more than 5 minutes old? (Also, I've noticed that the <code> tags in your comment don't work, which is as expected as that's not markdown.)

Comment: @EliahKagan: As a moderator, I can edit comments after the edit window has passed.