# How to use keyboard 'icon' in markdown?

Tags: support, answer-format, markdown, formatting

Guys, I was looking in a question when I found a different way to markup keyboard (combination of keys) to express commands. I cant found a previously answer about Markdown (except [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/348/what-html-and-or-markdown-code-is-allowed-in-comments), but not covering my question).

So I take the screenshot below (because I dont know how to call it ehehehe):

[image: markup keyboard shortcut like in this]

What is the Markdown tag used to show **Ctrl + D** as showed above?

Comment: Do you mean using the kbd tags? <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: [*Ask Ubuntu* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Answer (score 36):

Guys, I found it! just adding the html tag **kbd** as:

```
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
```

That will produce <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Would be very nice if someone able to edit http://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help and add this feature.

Comment: There should be an easier method to add these tags. Just try telling somebody to switch virtual teminals, do something, and press Ctrl+Z by hand-typing these tags.

Comment: https://kbd.hsuan.xyz Hi, I made a tool to capture shortcuts and generate `kbd` tags.

Answer (score 14):

This is HTML that works also in the used Markup language here on StackExchange. You would write `<kbd>F1</kbd>` to achieve <kbd>F1</kbd> (when it is surrounded by ` for code formatting, HTML is ignored). kbd is the abbreviation for keyboard.
Oh, and in comments you also have no HTML support.

For more information, look there:
https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting
https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#html

But anyway, I think this question is placed better on meta.AU, so I will flag it for migration.