# How do I get the button icons?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use keyboard 'icon' in markdown?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/707/how-to-use-keyboard-icon-in-markdown)

I've seen in some questions or answer that people are able to turn 'alt' or 'shift' into little button icons that say the name of the button.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<kbd>KEY</kbd>` gives <kbd>KEY</kbd>

And if you see something in the wild like that in the future, you can click the edit link to see the source for it.