# How to display keys and tags?

Tags: support, tags, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use keyboard 'icon' in markdown?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/707/how-to-use-keyboard-icon-in-markdown)

How do you display buttons on keyboard eg: Control, Alt etc. in your discussion? I have seen many people even displaying tags. How to do it?

Comment: What about tags???

Comment: tags are `[tag:unity]` and so on

Comment: [tag:Thanks]. It works.